# Error with practicalmeteor:mocha & Meteor 1.6

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

I'm getting the following error on terminal when tried to run practicalmeteor:mocha with Meteor 1.6

```
Uncaught TypeError: MochaRunner.runEverywhere is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After few trials I managed to fix the problem by doing the following updates to my project

```
coffeescript           upgraded from 1.0.17 to 1.12.7_3
coffeescript-compiler  added, version 1.12.7_3
```

To update one or more of these packages to their latest
compatible versions, pass their names to `meteor update`,

Comment: Had same issue, can confirm that this worked. Thanks!
//EDIT: for lazy (efficient) people, you can also run "meteor update --all-packages"

Comment: [Does not work for me](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/9026#issuecomment-348192131).